# Request timeout when trying to upload image (AFNetworking) in iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode6, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

This is the entire code we took from the example code and modified it..

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters1 = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/userimage.jpg"]];
NSString  *filePath2 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/userimage.jpg"];
NSLog(@"this is the filepath: %@", filePath);

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath2]){
  NSLog(@"file exists");
} else {
  NSLog(@"file does not exist");
}

[manager POST:@"http://192.168.0.2/my_project/public_html/test" parameters:parameters1 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
  [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

And this is the particular line which when commented, the request goes without timeout issue..

```
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
  [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
}
```